# How to convert the string['2019-06-01T23:07:02.000+0000'] to datetime object in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, strptime

I'm getting the following format date time strings from a JSON object and i want to convert it to a datetime object in Python, so that i can use it in my code.

```
'2019-06-01T23:07:02.000+0000'
```

As you can see the above string contains milliseconds and i couldn't find a formatter in strptime method for it.

```
datetime.strptime(incOpenTime, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ') #this works only against microseconds
```

I can parse the string and supply it to datetime object, but i'm hoping for a direct strptime format.

Comment: You can either use an updated string format, or use `dateutil.parser.parse`, check my answer below @ManikandarajS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want to change your formatter string to `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z`

```
In [25]: datetime.strptime('2019-06-01T23:07:02.000+0000','%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')                                                                                           
Out[25]: datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 1, 23, 7, 2, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Or you can use [datetutil.parser](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse) for the same, which doesn't need you to provide the format string

```
'2019-06-01T23:07:02.000+0000'
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d8d1b2eea17c> in <module>
----> 1 from datetutil import parser

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'datetutil'

In [2]: from dateutil import parser                                                                                                                                                    
In [4]: parser.parse('2019-06-01T23:07:02.000+0000')                                                                                                                                   
Out[4]: datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 1, 23, 7, 2, tzinfo=tzutc())
```